# Import wordpress posts to another wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, restore, posts

I had a website based on wordpress.Then domain has expired and now I registered a new domain and built a new website which is based on wordpress too.
Now I want to have my previous website's contents to be in the new one.
I didn't make any backup using wordpress export function, So import option in new website can't be useful.
The only thing is backed up is MYSQL database, how can I restore posts in the new website?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks friend for all your helps, I've tested all but none worked. I think I've lost posts and have to post them again (horrible !!)

Comment: Try to improve your question every time you try something. All the answers suggested here should work. What did you try so far and what results or errors did you get? Just saying they did not work is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Self Hosted Wordpress.org, You may use a suitable plugin for that

I found one here [Here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dbmanager/). You may find other options as well

Peace

Answer (score 0):

Just import your backup database into your new database. and change the siteUrl and wordpressUrl in wp_option table to new domain. Then updolad all the wordpress files from your old domain into your new domain, change the database connection info in wp-config.php settings. then it will work as before.

Comment: This method works, but if you have lots of posts and comments with back links to other posts in your blog, then you need to run a query to change those links to the new address. The second link in the answer above by songdogtech has instructions for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Export your old data [image]

you have a .gz file and import the same file to new site....